# Concurrency and restriction to Serializable

Tags: ajax, concurrency, wicket

I am currently writing on an application which requires me to compute something which will take some time to complete. Therefore, I am doing this computation in the background. I now implemented a solution which starts new `Thread`s for each such request via an `ExecutorService`. These threads regularly report their progress back to a (`volatile`) `IModel`. Additionally, I am using an `AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior` which updates the website by printing the progress which is represented by this `IModel` to the screen. By doing so, the website stays responsive, the task can be interrupted by a button click and the HTTP request which was requesting the long lasting task does not time out.

However, Wicket does not like non-`Serializable` references in its `WebPage` or `Panel`instances and I wonder what would be the best way of solving this problem. For now, I wrote a little manager class which uses a cash which is referenced by a `static` variable which is how I am avoiding the serialization restriction. The `WebPage` instance which was triggering the task now only holds a reference to a unique ID which was assigned to it by my manager class when invoking the task.

Of course, with this approach I have to clean up after myself and I am also concerned about security, since I did not yet take actions to avoid interferences of tasks started by different users. Also, it just feels wrong to me, since I want to keep this task on the scope of the `WebPage` instead of letting the task escape into a global environment. I am sure, there is a better way to do this!

Thanks for any thoughts on this matter and for sharing your experience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach sound perfectly reasonable: Pass the task-handling to a non-web instance (could be a Spring managed singleton) and just keep an identifier in your component/model.